# is it ok to use a key in Session for the current user's Role?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

Can I just use Session["role"] = "theRole", or that would be a bad practice, so I would create my custom authorize attribute where I'm going to look into the Session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise against it. .Net already has plenty of built in functionality to implement security features.  Don't re-invent the wheel, especially where security is concerned.

You do not need to implement a membership provider.  All you need to do is set `HttpContext.User` to a custom [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) and you can use `User.IsInRole("role")` and `[AuthorizeAttribute(Roles="role")]`.

I would suggest role information is more suited to the authorization ticket than the session.  Storing the data in the session could cause added problems of syncing the session lifespan with the authorization ticket lifespan.  The session could possibly expire while the user is still logged in.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a simple example for us? I am learning about this right now and your answer seems great, but an example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Generally anytime you're rolling your own security, it's questionable at best.  Is there some reason you can't use the built-in User object and IsInRole method to make your determination?

Comment: What is it that is questionable, and why? Rolling your own security, or caching Role in Session?

Comment: to use the built-in IsInRole you must use asp.net roleprovider or create a custom one, but you have to implement the default one which has a lot of stuff that i'm going to need to just leave it as to throw not implement exception

Comment: Gee ... I've *never* done that and I've used it in at least 10 apps in production.  user.IsInRole("MyAdminGroup") ....

Comment: @Omu You don't need to implement a role provider to use User.IsInRole() you just need to set HttpContext.User to a custom IPrincipal for each request.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with creating a custom role provider that only overrides one method, if that method is all you require for your application to work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not bad, but the good principle is to use the Principal object and using the membership provider to answer your queries for Roles.

Comment: I like how you used 'principle' and 'principal' in the same sentence. :x

Comment: Probably you need to re read the sentence. I was talking about a principle, and the principle suggest usage of Principal. You can replace the word principle with "general practice" for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new Session variable, how about using the existing **HttpContext.Current.User**? That is in the System.Security.Principal namespace.

It has an array of roles which you can populate, and then test against by using `if (thisUser.IsInRole("admin"))`...

Just for illustration purposes, here is one way to populate the roles in a manually-authenticated User. In most situations, you will already have the authenticated user.

```
System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity id = new FormsIdentity(new FormsAuthenticationTicket("dok", false, 30));
        string[] roles = { "admin" };
        HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
```

Comment: you can't populate that array

Answer (score 0):

Or if you have custom security roles you can build you own classes holding all the information you need then after login save the whole class to the session to save querying the dabase everytime you need the information

Answer (score 0):

Custom authorize attribute is better as it is easily to inject on actions and also there is one place where your authentication/authorization logic resides.